# Laravel export file with dynamic name

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, filenames, laravel-excel

I am running a script that stores the collected data in csv. It's working like that:

```
$responce =  Excel::store(new UsersExport($formatted_data), 'fileName.csv', null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV);
```

And that's my class:

```
class UsersExport implements FromArray
{
    protected $invoices;

    public function __construct(array $invoices)
    {
        $this->invoices = $invoices;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        return $this->invoices;
    }
}
```

So far the filename is hardcoded and I want to make it dynamic. It should be changed with the year and the month every time I run new export (2020-01.csv or something like that) The script is running with two parameters - year and month.

```
protected $signature = 'select:values {--year=} {--month=}';
```

In the where clause I am filtering like that:

```
->whereMonth('ut', $this->option('month'))   
->whereYear('ut', $this->option('year'))
```

Tried with

```
Excel::store(new UsersExport($formatted_data)->withFilename()
```

But it does not work...I have not found something similar to my solution so far. Any ideas on how to fix that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is:
With simple php concatenation...

`$fileName = $this->option('year')."-".$this->option('month').".csv";`

And putting the variable in the export like this:
`$responce =  Excel::store(new UsersExport($formatted_data), $fileName ,null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV);`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
$responce = Excel::store(new UsersExport($formatted_data), now()->format('Y-m').'.csv', null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV);
```

Comment: It's naming the file with the current year and month `2022-10.csv`.  Ignoring the params

Comment: have you tried `Excel::store(new UsersExport($formatted_data), $this->option('month').'-'.$this->option('year'), null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV);`

Comment: Yes of course like that - `$this->option('filename')` and adding option in the command `{--filename}`. But that's not very dynamic isn't it (: